# Django base template location

Tags: django, django-templates

I am creating a website using Django 2.0.7. I need to use a base template that is outside the purview of all applications, but can be inherited and used by templates in my other applications in the project.

I have edited my settings.py file appropriately (as per the documentation), but still when I go the root (i.e. home) page of my site, I get a blank page - can anyone explain why?

## I have the following directory structure

```
myproj
    ----manage.py
    ----app1
    ----templates/
            base.html
            index.html
    ----static/
    ----myproj
            __initi__.py
            wsgi.py
            settings.py
            urls.py
            views.py # <- I added this
```

## The relevant parts of my settings.ini file looks like this:

```
BASE_DIR = os.path.dirname(os.path.dirname(os.path.abspath(__file__)))
SITE_ROOT = os.path.dirname(os.path.realpath(__file__))

TEMPLATES = [
    {
        'BACKEND': 'django.template.backends.django.DjangoTemplates',
        'DIRS': ['{0}/templates/'.format(BASE_DIR),],
        'APP_DIRS': True,
        'OPTIONS': {
            'context_processors': [
                'django.template.context_processors.debug',
                'django.template.context_processors.request',
                'django.contrib.auth.context_processors.auth',
                'django.contrib.messages.context_processors.messages',
            ],
        },
    },
]
```

## views.py:

```
from django.http import HttpResponse


def index(request):
    return HttpResponse()
```

Why can't django find my index.html ?

Comment: Where are you telling your project to render that template? At the moment, you are telling your index view to return an empty response.

Comment: @dfundako Do I need to **explicitly** call render in my view function? I didn't need to do that in the previous versions of django (1.7, 1.8) that I used before IIRC.

Comment: Well yeah. You tell your urls.py file what view to go find when someone goes to the path you define, and when it reads the view, you need to tell it what to render. As it sits, how do you think def index() would have any idea to render your index.html/base.html? Put '<h1>Hello</h1>' into your httpresponse and see what happens.

Comment: @dfundako OK, this has definitely changed since I last wrote a django website using the earlier versions I mentioned. Previously, the name of the template was automagically inferred from the name of the function.

I will remove this question now.

Comment: No need to close question unless it is a dupe. I can put my comments into an answer in case others have the same question.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Use `'DIRS': [os.path.join(BASE_DIR, "templates")]` in your settings, and your view should return a object which knows what template to render, like this one:

```
from django.shortcuts import render

def index(request):
    return render(request, 'index.html')
```

There's also [TemplateResponse(), SimpleTemplateResponse()](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/2.0/ref/template-response/) and other objects you can return, depending on your needs.